# async.each not waiting for loop to complete?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, async.js, nightmare

I'm reading links from a text file and making requests with nightmare js to get some data. Since i want to wait for each request to be finished, i'm using the sync library to loop through the links and execute the request function, and only when it is finished, proceed to the next iteration. Here's my code:

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const fs = require('fs');
const async = require('async');

const url = 'https://lojaonline.claro.com.br/celular';

const lerArquivo = () => {
    //var links = []
    /*lr.eachLine('links.txt', function(link, isUltimoLink) {
        console.log(link);
        links.push(link);
        if (isUltimoLink) {
            return false; // para de ler
        }
    });*/
    var links = require('fs').readFileSync('links.txt', 'utf-8').split('\n')
    async.each(links, getPrecos, function(erro){
        if(erro){
            console.log('Erro: ');
            console.log(erro);
        }else{
            console.log('Ok');
        }
    });
}

function getPrecos (endereco) {
    console.log('Recuperando dados de ' + endereco);
    const nightmare = new Nightmare({show: false, gotoTimeout: 999999999, waitTimeout: 999999999});
    //acessando a página
    try{
         nightmare.goto(endereco).wait('input[id="edit-cep-part1"]')
                                .type('input[id="edit-cep-part1"]', '51030')
                                .wait('input[id="edit-cep-part2"]')
                                .type('input[id="edit-cep-part2"]', '560')
                                .click('input[value="Confirmar"]');     
    }catch (e){
        console.error(e);
    }
    //recuperando as informações
    try{
        nightmare.wait('#plans-tab').evaluate(function(){           
            return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr.body')).map(element => element.innerText);          
        })  
        .end()
        .then(function(result){
            console.log(result);
        });
    }catch(e){
        console.error(e);
    }
};

lerArquivo();
```

I wanted to output something like this:

```
console.log('Recuperando dados de ' + link1);
//
//data
//
console.log('Recuperando dados de ' + link2);
//
//data
//
console.log('Recuperando dados de ' + link3);
//
//data
//
```

But i'm getting:

```
console.log('Recuperando dados de ' + link1);
console.log('Recuperando dados de ' + link2);
console.log('Recuperando dados de ' + link3);
```

And then the data is fetched. Which means that the loop isn't waiting for the function to complete. What am i missing here?

Comment: Use `eachSeries`: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: It's a bit disappointing that this question is still marked as unanswered because there are actually no answer posted, but the comments already have the answer. So it will always show as if it was never answered. :/